# $x + 4y - 6 = 0, y + x - 5/2 = 0$ equals $(x,y) = (4/3, \ 7/6)$ ...how ???

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's been a while since I have taken a math class, and I forgot simple stuff like this. So I am doing a differential equation I don't get this part of the problem.

$x + 4y - 6 = 0 $

$y + x - 5/2 = 0 $

how did they get it to equal ?

$(x,y) = (4/3, \ 7/6) $

Comment: [Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SystemsTwoVrble.aspx) is a refresher.

Comment: subtract both to get $y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the top equation for $x$ in terms of $y$:  $x = 6-4y.$

Substitute this into the second equation:

$$y + (6 - 4y) - \frac{5}{2} = 0;$$
$$-3y + \frac{7}{2} = 0;$$
$$y = \frac{7}{6}.$$

Then substitute this back into one of the equations (like the first one):

$$x + 4\frac{7}{6}  - 6 = 0;$$
$$x = \frac{4}{3}.$$

Comment: thank you so much JOHN!...been trying to figure it out for the last half an hour!